# python print string from variable name in string

Tags: python, string

I want to display a text. and in the text there is a variable name, and the name of the variable is already in the previous definition.

example code

```
my_dict = {}
my_dict['name']='Candra'

#I want to be like this
print('my name is {name}')

#not like this
print('my name is '+ my_dict['name'])
```

Comment: The closest you can get is `print('my name is {name}'.format(name=my_dict['name']))`.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this :

```
print "my name is {}".format(my_dict['name'])
```

Output : `my name is Sandra`

Other ways : `print "my name is %s" % my_dict['name']`

Answer (score 0):

you could do this easily with python 3

```
my_dict = {}
my_dict['name']='Candra'
name = my_dict['name']


a = f"He said his name is {name}."
print(a)
```

output would be

```
He said his name is Candra.
```